# What's the difference between using a.var and a.var()

Tags: c++

Just for example

```
Class A{
    public: 
    int a;    
};

int main(){
    A test;
    int b = test.a;
    int c = test.a();  
}
```

My question is that when accessing the member variable of a class, is there any difference between using `test.a` and `test.a()`?

Comment: `.a()` would be a function call...calling an int doesn't make much sense.

Comment: It is not `Class` it should be `class`.

Comment: compiling it would have told you: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/568cdb5bd37ec26f

Comment: Maybe you should get [a good C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list?lq=1) and learn the language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here `test.a()` is a call to `a` function whereas `test.a` is access to your object's public variable, both are different things.

Also, your syntax is incorrect it should be `class` instead of `Class`.

Answer (score 0):

There is a big difference. `test.a` works, `test.a()` doesn't.

`test.a()` is a function call, `a` in `class A` is not a function.